# Remove known HDD user password when hdd is connected externally

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

I have recently moved from a HDD to a SSD.
The HDD has a user password on it(which I know), but since I already have the SSD installed in my laptop, I would like to disable/type in this password without reinstalling the HDD in my laptop.

I have a cheap i-tec USB3 external hdd adapter to do this.

The HDD is a Western Digital Scorpio Blue 750GB (WD7500BPVT)

I have a Windows 7, 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS available to do this.
Is this possible?

Comment: What is the model of the HDD?

Comment: @Hex See Edited question.

Comment: You may try `mhdd` low level tool. Unfortunately not all USB2SATA adapters supporting direct access to hard drive. If `mhdd` wouldn't able to connect to HDD then the only choice is to hook HDD back to computer, otherwise `mhdd` would allow you to remove password if you know it.

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I just put the hdd back in, removed the password, then removed it again. If you could post that as an answer for future reference, I would accept it.

Comment: Yes, sure I will move it to the answer, so may be somebody will find it helpful. I had just twice pretty good usb2sata adapters that allowed to access directly SATA drives(unfortunately lost both of them) that's why I doubted it would work in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `mhdd` low level tool. Unfortunately not all USB2SATA adapters supporting direct access to hard drive. If `mhdd` wouldn't able to connect to HDD then the only choice is to hook HDD back to computer, otherwise `mhdd` would allow you to remove password if you know it.

Comment: Perhaps you can mention what OS that tool works on...

Comment: @jiggunjer `mhdd` must work in real CPU mode (read in clear DOS). Utility usually comes with bootable CD that boot mostly in freedos. I run it over network boot (if computer support it) with PXE enabled on computer by using `syslinux` on the server and configured to  run `mhdd` in `memdisk` mode